# iperf 2 hangs with multiple udp streams

Tags: linux, udp, ubuntu-14.04, iperf

When I run iperf UDP test with multiple threads, it simply hangs. It never returns. But the same test always successfully completes with single stream. Here is my iperf version and details:

```
$ iperf --v
iperf version 2.0.5 (08 Jul 2010) pthreads
```

The client (10.20.32.50) command: `$ iperf -c 10.20.32.52 -P 2 -t 10 -u -b 1g`

The server (10.20.32.52) command: `$ iperf -s -u`

The client gives following output and never finishes

```
$ iperf -c 10.20.32.52 -P 2 -t 10 -u -b 1g                           
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.20.32.52, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  4] local 10.20.32.50 port 33635 connected with 10.20.32.52 port 5001
[  3] local 10.20.32.50 port 56336 connected with 10.20.32.52 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   483 MBytes   406 Mbits/sec
[  4] Sent 344820 datagrams
[  4] Server Report:
[  4]  0.0-696.8 sec   483 MBytes  5.82 Mbits/sec   0.020 ms  229/344819 (0.066%)
[  4]  0.0-696.8 sec  478 datagrams received out-of-order
```

The server output is following

```
$ iperf -s -u
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[ 12] local 10.20.32.52 port 5001 connected with 10.20.32.50 port 60971
[ 10] local 10.20.32.52 port 5001 connected with 10.20.32.50 port 34388
[ 10]  0.0-823.4 sec   483 MBytes  4.92 Mbits/sec   0.018 ms  420/344819 (0.12%)
[ 10]  0.0-823.4 sec  365 datagrams received out-of-order
```

My both client/server machines are 32 cores with 10 Gbps. Note that client runs fine with the single thread/stream, i.e., `$ iperf -c 10.20.32.52 -P 1 -t 10 -u -b 1g` always completes. Any help is appreciated!

This question was originally asked as a response to similar question [1], but with iperf3. I made a separate question after receiving suggestions to do so.

Nodir

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836985/iperf3-parallel-udp-not-running/32728777

Comment: Have you ever found an answer on this? the question for iperf3 is not available. Did you try iperf3 and was the problem solved then?

Comment: No, I did not find an answer. I did not try with iperf3 either. Let me quickly try with iperf3 and see if that helps.

Comment: iperf3 does not have this problem. I successfully run up to 4 parallel streams with iperf3. I also get higher throughput (around 10%) with iperf3. I'd suggest to move to iperf3.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Nodir. I've investigated moving to iperf3 but it seems that multicast traffic is not ok in this version yet and is planned for 3.1 .